# CSS, target element befor and after text

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to target element that is before and after text. For example:

```
<button><i class="icon user"> User</button>
<button>User <i class="icon user"></button>
```

So basically I would like to be able to assign margin left/right to .icon depending if before or after text.

I tried using pseudo `:first-child`, `:last-child`, but that does not work.

I know that wrapping text in another container like

`<button><span>User</span> <i class="icon user"></button>` will give me access to it, but I'm trying to minimize html markup

Comment: If you know where your text will be, you can just add margin to that side. But if it is random, the simplest and javascript-less approach would be to enclose the text and give a margin to it like you said.

Comment: You are missing the closing tags for `</i>` and yes it's possible if you close the tags properly. For the first one, target `<i>` in your `CSS` and for the other one, target the the `<button>`. That should give you the ***before*** and ***after*** customization. You can also use `i:after` and `i:before` in `CSS` which will give the same effect.

Comment: @Vladimir Jovanović thats not going to work. I need to add padding/margin between text and icon, not button itself. Also <i> tag already uses ::before for rendering font icons